# Не могу создать ServerSocket на любом порту. В чем проблема?

Tags: java, сокет, javafx

Сам эксепшен:

> java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind

- Платформа: Windows 10 x64
- IDE: IDEA.
- java version "1.8.0_111" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
  1.8.0_111-b14) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)
- Приложение делается на `javaFX`. Интерфейс на `FXML` (Если это поможет)
- Если я создам новый класс и там опишу создание сокета, все заработает. Но в составе моего приложения на команде `serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);` вылетает выше упомянутый эксепшен.
- Команда netstat не вывела порты которые я использовал (4444, 4343, 5555, 5454)

Вот части кода:

**Main.java**:

```
public class Main extends Application{
private Stage primaryStage;
private BorderPane rootLayout;
private TaskJournal taskJournal;
private Database database;
private TMServer server;

private TableView<Task> taskTable;

private ObservableList<Task> taskList;

public Main() {
    taskJournal = TaskJournalController.getInstance();
    database = Database.getInstance();
    taskList = taskJournal.getTaskList();
    server = new ServerController().getInstance();
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    this.primaryStage.setTitle("Task manager");

    initRootLayout();
    showTaskOverview();

    database.set(Database.DatabaseType.SERIALIZE);
    taskJournal.start();


    AlertingSystemController asc = AlertingSystemController.getInstance();
    asc.setObservableList(taskList);
    asc.showSysTray();
    asc.runAlertingSystem();
    server.start(); //Запуск сервера
}
```

**ServerController.java**:

```
public class ServerController implements TMServer {

    private static ServerController instance;

    private final int port = 5454;
    private static ServerSocket serverSocket;

    public ServerController() {
        try {
            System.out.println("run server. Port = " + port);
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public ServerController getInstance() {
        if(instance == null) {
            instance = new ServerController();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(){
        try {
            new ConnectController(serverSocket.accept());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        try {
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Полный `e.printStackTrace();`

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:106)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:387)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:190)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:128)
    at sample.server.controller.ServerController.<init>(ServerController.java:23)
    at sample.server.controller.ServerController.getInstance(ServerController.java:31)
    at sample.server.Main.<init>(Main.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:819)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Очень похоже на занятый порт. `netstat -a` эти порты показывает?

Comment: Дело в том, что если я создам отдельный класс со своей точкой входа (psvm) то все создается отлично, на тех же портах.

Comment: Я грешу в сторону `extends Application` класса Main. `netstat -a` тоже не показывает эти порты.

Comment: подозреваю что где-то два раза создается сокет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При выполнении строки:

```
server = new ServerController().getInstance();
```

создание `ServerSocket` происходит два раза.

Сначала вызывается конструктор `ServerController()`, который создает сокет:

```
serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
```

далее вызывается метод `getInstance()`, во время вызова которого `instance == null` и конструктор `ServerController()` вызывается второй раз:

```
instance = new ServerController()
```

Ваш синглтон вовсе им не является (и используете Вы его неправильно). Почитайте про построение [синглтона](http://www.javenue.info/post/2).

Класс `ServerController` в самом простом случае будет выглядеть **примерно** так:

```
public final class ServerController {
    private static ServerController instance;
    private final int port = 5454;
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;

    private ServerController() {
        try {
            System.out.println("run server. Port = " + port);
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static synchronized ServerController getInstance() {
        if(instance == null) {
            instance = new ServerController();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    ...

}
```

Также можете добавить сюда double-checked locking.

Comment: Тогда вопрос, как исправить?

Comment: Понял. Убарать new

Comment: Такая мелкая ошибка, из за моей невнимательномти, на которую я потратил не один час... Спасибо Вам!

Comment: @ЕвгенийТупиков, Вам нужно перестроить класс `ServerController`, посмотрите ссылку, которую я привел.

Answer (score 1):

паттерн `Singelton` не правильно реализован, вместо:

```
public ServerController getInstance(){}
```

надо:

```
public static ServerController getInstance(){}
```

тогда вместо:

```
server = new ServerController().getInstance();
```

надо:

```
server = ServerController.getInstance();
```

Comment: Да, благодаря post_zeew я понял  чем ошибка!

Comment: А лихо Вы содержание-то поменяли :)

Comment: @post_zeew смутил сначала комент, что в psvm все ок, а в javafx не работает :)